# .NET Core app not accessible outside Linux server

Tags: linux, networking, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to access an app (Identity Server 4) that is hosted on my server at home. When I run app, I can curl localhost and get HTML of home page of Identity Server 4. But, when I try to access that app from my PC I constantly get "connection refused". I have open the port (in this case port is 5000) with ufw, but I still get "connection refused".

I don't know what should I be looking at, cause I am not very good with networking.

If I open

> /etc/hosts

I get:

> 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain
>   localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

And if I type ifconfig I get:

> br-23aec2d805c1: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
>           inet6 fe80::42:aff:fed1:afcf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether 02:42:0a:d1:af:cf  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> br-a03307c6e330: flags=4099  mtu 1500
>           inet 172.21.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.21.255.255
>           ether 02:42:dc:aa:49:c9  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> br-b2ac2102790e: flags=4099  mtu 1500
>           inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
>           ether 02:42:9b:c4:58:a2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 68  bytes 5908 (5.7 KiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 68  bytes 5908 (5.7 KiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> docker0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
>           inet6 fe80::42:ccff:feb4:83d4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether 02:42:cc:b4:83:d4  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 22655  bytes 5132534 (4.8 MiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 26492  bytes 20375012 (19.4 MiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> docker_gwbridge: flags=4099  mtu 1500
>           inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
>           ether 02:42:7d:64:08:fa  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 3763  bytes 690577 (674.3 KiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 2977  bytes 1193212 (1.1 MiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> eno1: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet 192.168.1.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>           inet6 fe80::2111:8d94:12e1:3617  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether 70:85:c2:7b:24:b5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 669595  bytes 799790693 (762.7 MiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 476491  bytes 45305847 (43.2 MiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>           device interrupt 16  memory 0xa1200000-a1220000
>
> lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
>           inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>           inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
>           loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
>           RX packets 68  bytes 5908 (5.7 KiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 68  bytes 5908 (5.7 KiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> veth0e6a280: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet6 fe80::245e:eff:feeb:1bc2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether 26:5e:0e:eb:1b:c2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 156515  bytes 36954031 (35.2 MiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 135009  bytes 27523494 (26.2 MiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> veth0ed3eff: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet6 fe80::88e6:81ff:fe80:1a6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether 8a:e6:81:80:01:a6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 1074962  bytes 171060799 (163.1 MiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 788326  bytes 341834817 (325.9 MiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> veth37e347a: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet6 fe80::f0c3:60ff:fe57:c5dd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether f2:c3:60:57:c5:dd  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 788306  bytes 341833385 (325.9 MiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 1074982  bytes 171062231 (163.1 MiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> veth54e612a: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet6 fe80::68a9:31ff:fe5b:f1f7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether 6a:a9:31:5b:f1:f7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 15416  bytes 4958650 (4.7 MiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 15485  bytes 862685 (842.4 KiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> veth7c3ac57: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet6 fe80::d0d1:2dff:feed:f1bd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether d2:d1:2d:ed:f1:bd  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 28  bytes 3522 (3.4 KiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 42  bytes 5131 (5.0 KiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> veth86f6af5: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet6 fe80::e44d:3cff:fe01:6991  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether e6:4d:3c:01:69:91  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 3763  bytes 690577 (674.3 KiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 2977  bytes 1193212 (1.1 MiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> vethda6b63a: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet6 fe80::d4db:9eff:fece:d3bc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
>           ether d6:db:9e:ce:d3:bc  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 133961  bytes 27038265 (25.7 MiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 155294  bytes 37135106 (35.4 MiB)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

I am lost and I don't know what to do.
What part should I modify and with what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you running the server? Is it using Kestrel, for example?  Checking [its current documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2) indicates:

> The Listen method binds to a TCP socket, and an options lambda permits X.509 certificate configuration

So it looks like you should be able to use something like:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
 // ...
 .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
 {
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer were pretty simple, but yet it never crossed my mind.
Tanktalus was so close. When I used ConfigureKestrel, VS couldn't find that method, so instead of his sample, I used almost the same thing but with different method.
This is the solution:

```
.UseKestrel(configure =>
{
     configure.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 5055);
})
```